# How can convert view page into a pdf in Yii

Tags: pdf, yii

How can convert view page into a pdf in Yii from controller.
in main.php i added this code

```
 'ePdf' => array(
        'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
        'params'        => array(
            'mpdf'     => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.mpdf.*',
                'constants'         => array(
                    '_MPDF_TEMP_PATH' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.runtime'),
                ),
                'class'=>'mpdf', // the literal class filename to be loaded from the vendors folder
            ),
            'HTML2PDF' => array(
                'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.html2pdf.*',
                'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap

            )
        ),
    ),
```

Controller Code is

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('', 'A5');
$mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('printformat', array(), true));
$mPDF1->Output();
```

Error : include(mpdf.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error says, you have to include **mpdf.php** before using it.

You are using **YiiPdf** Bundle with **html2pdf** and **mpdf**.

First download Yii Pdf from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/files/yii-pdf-0.3.2.zip) and include in extension as protected/extensions/yii-pdf (ext.yii-pdf as in `'class' => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',`). This means your extension folder contains yii-pdf as directory.

Then, download mpdf from [here.](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/download) and place it in vendors as protected/vendors/mpdf as in

```
'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.mpdf.*',
```

All explanation is [here.](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/#hh3)